# Checking whether a JSON dictionary is empty or not and storing in a list

Tags: python, json, loops, instagram-api

I have an Instagram API which I load into a JSON. The response is coming properly and I am even able to fetch the id from the data received. Then I save it in a python list and put it in an Excel sheet using openpyxl.

Here is the catch. While loading the values, If there is no response from API in case of a deleted instagram account,where the JSON will be empty, I want to store "ACC deleted" in the list.

(NOTE :- I also referred similar questions but didnt get my answer which works.)

Here is the code:

```
for r in range(1,51):
    var=r,test.cell(row=r,column=1).value
    xy=var[1]
    myopener=Myopener()
    url=myopener.open('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='+xy+'&count=1&access_token=641567093.1fb234f.a0ffbe574e844e1c818145097050cf33')

    **beta=json.load(url)
    for item in beta['data']:
        list.append(item['id'])** //*HERE I WANT THE CHANGE*


    for j in range(len(list)):
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=j+1, max_row=j+1):
            for cell in row:
                cell.value=list[j]
                wb.save('sample.xlsx')
```

The json Response is this:

```
{
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  [
 {
  "username": "rawhawk_sk",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12724928_109384759877664_1105313598_a.jpg",
  "id": "670907103",
  "full_name": "shwan mcswan"
}
]
}
```

If the json response is empty like below, how to store "ACC deleted" in the list?

```
{
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if data is empty in your script and if so add a new entry 'ACC deleted' to the list.

```
import json

jsons = []
jsons.append("""{
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  [
 {
  "username": "rawhawk_sk",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12724928_109384759877664_1105313598_a.jpg",
  "id": "670907103",
  "full_name": "shwan mcswan"
}
]
}
""")

jsons.append("""{
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  []
} """)

output_list = []

for txt in jsons:
    beta = json.loads(txt)
    if beta.get('data'):
        for item in beta['data']:
            output_list.append(item['id'])
    else:
        output_list.append('ACC deleted')

print(output_list)
```

Comment: I think you did not get the question right @Ashafix . I want to store "Acc deleted" in the list("list") where I append the data when the response from the API is like the above empty json.

Comment: I tried it. Its not right. The Json is skipping the empty dictionary and getting the next result and then its gets in the list.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? The code provided in the question is not a minimal working code and it is therefore a bit hard to guess what else is happening. The code snippet in my answer simply checks whether the data field is empty in the JSON and if yes, 'ACC deleted' is added to the list.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. Well, I want the exact thing which you mentioned. The code to check whether the data field is empty and if yes, "ACC deleted" gets appended to the list. It is not happening with the the code snippet you provided. Let me explain. As you can see in the first code, the json loads the URL and stores it in a variable called "beta" From the JSON schema, if URL response gives out the JSON as the third code snippet which i provided, It should append "ACC deleted" in the list ("list")

Comment: I tried it with your empty JSON response and in this case it appends 'ACC deleted' to the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110266/discussion-between-ashafix-and-rohit-nair).

Comment: Thank you so much! It was my fault only. I mistyped something. The code is perfect! +1

Comment: Hello @Ashafix I need a small favour! I know i should not do this but I need a help desperately and I know you might have an answer. Do read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024266/how-to-overcome-valueerror-read-of-closed-file-in-python-3-5-1    i have posted and try to reply. Thanks in advance!